# convert matlab code of size function to python

Tags: python, matlab

What does the code
 `fill_value(1,1,:) = [0; 255; 255];` 
do

Comment: Well Stackoverflow is not a code-conversion site.
http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: ok. what does fill_value(1,1,:) = [0; 255; 255]; do?

Answer (score 2):

1. Understand what it does
2. Read the docs for [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)
3. Write the Python code

Comment: +1 This reminds me of the Feynman algorithm